# NetTrain automatic settings

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to compare Mathematica's [`NetTrain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetTrain.html) with other algorithms, and I used `Automatic` settings as they were working quite well.

Now I need to include those results in a paper, but I don't know which method mathematica choose for training.

There are three of those - [ADAM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/220494), [RMSProp](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/243881) and [SGD](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/OptimizationStochasticGradientDescent/), by altering between those and comparing performance with automatic I found out that ADAM seems to be the one used for my case. But I still don't know a lot of parameters like `"LearningRate"`, `"LearningRateSchedule"`, etc. Is there a way to find them out?

Comment: Sometimes you can get at these with ``Internal`InheritedBlock``. Do you have a sample net to work with? The settings may change. In any case you can always look through the `DownValues` with ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal``.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For now, you can use the "cheat code" `` NeuralNetworks`Private`MXTrainer`$OptimizerSpec ``, which will show the current defaults for the different methods (some internal details are mixed in here):

```
In[32]:= NeuralNetworks`Private`MXTrainer`$OptimizerSpec/.NeuralNetworks`Defaulting[_,d_]:>d//GeneralUtilities`PrettyForm
Out[32]= <|
    ADAM -> {
        {ADAM, #}&,
        <|Beta1 -> 0.9, Beta2 -> 0.999, Epsilon -> Rational[1, 100000]|>
    },
    SGD -> {
        {SGD, #}&,
        <|Momentum -> 0.93, LearningRateSchedule -> Polynomial|>
    },
    RMSProp -> {
        {RMSProp, #}&,
        <|
            Beta -> 0.95, Momentum -> 0.9, Epsilon -> Rational[1, 100000000]
        |>
    },
    $CommonSuboptions -> <|
        L2Regularization -> ArrayCasesT[Nullable[TensorT[{}, RealT]], 0.],
        GradientClipping -> ArrayCasesT[Nullable[TensorT[{}, RealT]], None],
        WeightClipping -> ArrayCasesT[Nullable[TensorT[{}, RealT]], None],
        InitialLearningRate -> Automatic, LearningRateSchedule -> None, GradientsBag -> None,
        GradientMapper -> RMSEnergy
    |>
|>
```

The rule is currently that SGD is used for networks with less than 128 parameters (total weight components), otherwise ADAM is used.

Comment: what the default learning rate of each methods?

Comment: For the ADAM case, I can see that $beta1 = 0.9$, $beta2 = 0.999$, $epsilon = 1e-5$. But what is the main parameter $alpha$?

Comment: This doesn't work on Mathematica 11.3.