# What are the default parameters for ADAM optimizer?

Tags: undocumented, neural-networks

ADAM Optimizer (used for optimizing the loss function for neural networks) consists of 3 free parameters:

- $\eta$, stepsize/learning rate
- $\beta_1$, forgetting factor for gradients
- $\beta_2$, forgetting factor for second moments of gradients
- $\epsilon$, smallest number for preventing division by $0$.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#Adam) for more information.

From the Mathematica documentation, $\beta_1 = 0.9$ and $\beta_2 = 0.999$. But what are the values for $\eta$ and $\epsilon$?

Comment: Someone has tried to answer this question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153708/nettrain-automatic-settings), but their code is buggy and doesn't show what eta is.

Comment: I think this is how you change these parameters since it doesn't give an error during training: `Method -> { "ADAM", "LearningRate" -> 0.001, "Beta1" -> 0.9, 
  "Beta2" -> 0.999, "Epsilon" -> Rational[1, 100000]}`

Comment: I also found this [Wolfram tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/applications/neuralnetworks/tutorial/NeuralNetworkTutorial.html) where under "Training Algorithm" they talk about how a default learning rate is chosen. However, when I manually choose a learning rate based on their formula (eta = (max(x) - min(x))/2), I CLEARLY get deferent results (i.e. little to nothing training).

Comment: Mathematica uses MxNet and the default values MxNet are:
learning_rate=0.001, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8
The come from [this website](https://machinelearningmastery.com/adam-optimization-algorithm-for-deep-learning/)